# aparecen simbolos raros al usar phpexcel

Tags: php

Buenas al usar phpexcel no me descarga el documento, solo aparecen unos simbolos raros, agradeceria enormemente vustra ayuda. Gracias de antemano.

```
$conexion = new mysqli('','','','');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("La conexión con el servidor de base de datos falló: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}      

$fecha1=$_GET['dateIni'];
$fecha2=$_GET['dateFin'];
$est=$_GET['est'];
$col=$_GET['col'];

if($fecha2!='' and $fecha1!='' and $est!='todo' and $col!='nada'){
    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM contratoscolaborador WHERE fecha>='$fecha1' AND fecha<='$fecha2' AND finalizado='$est' AND comercial='$col' ORDER BY fecha DESC";
    $misContratos = $conexion->query($consulta);
    ECHO "HOLAprimero";
    $n = "valor1";
}elseif($fecha2!='' and $fecha1!='' and $est=='todo' and $col=='nada'){
    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM contratoscolaborador WHERE fecha>='$fecha1' AND fecha<='$fecha2' ORDER BY fecha DESC";
    $misContratos = $conexion->query($consulta);
    ECHO "HOLAsegundo";
    $n = "valor2";
}elseif($fecha2=='' and $fecha1=='' and $est!='todo' and $col=='nada'){
    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM contratoscolaborador WHERE finalizado='$est' ORDER BY fecha DESC";
    $misContratos = $conexion->query($consulta);
    ECHO "HOLAtercero";
    $n = "valor3";
}elseif($fecha1=='' and $fecha2=='' and $est=='todo' and $col!='nada'){
    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM contratoscolaborador WHERE comercial='$col' ORDER BY fecha DESC";
    $misContratos = $conexion->query($consulta);
    ECHO "HOLAcuarto";
    $n = "valor4";
}elseif($fecha1!='' and $fecha2!='' and $est!='todo' and $col=='nada'){
    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM contratoscolaborador WHERE fecha>='$fecha1' AND fecha<='$fecha2' AND finalizado='$est' ORDER BY fecha DESC";
    $misContratos = $conexion->query($consulta);
    ECHO "HOLAquitno";
    $n = "valor5";
}elseif($fecha1=='' and $fecha2=='' and $est!='todo' and $col!='nada'){
    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM contratoscolaborador WHERE comercial='$col' AND finalizado='$est' ORDER BY fecha DESC";
    $misContratos = $conexion->query($consulta);
    ECHO "HOLAsexto";
    $n = "valor6";
}elseif($fecha1!='' and $fecha2!='' and $est=='todo' and $col!='nada'){
    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM contratoscolaborador WHERE comercial='$col' AND fecha>='$fecha1' AND fecha<='$fecha2' ORDER BY fecha DESC";
    $misContratos = $conexion->query($consulta);
    ECHO "HOLAultimo";
    $n = "valor7";
}
echo $n;

if($misContratos->num_rows > 0 ){

    if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli')
        die('Este archivo solo se puede ver desde un navegador web');

    /** Se agrega la libreria PHPExcel */
    require_once 'lib/PHPExcel/PHPExcel.php';

    // Se crea el objeto PHPExcel
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

    // Se asignan las propiedades del libro
    $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("") //Autor
                         ->setLastModifiedBy("") //Ultimo usuario que lo modificó
                         ->setTitle("Datos del Contrato")
                         ->setSubject("Cliente")
                         ->setDescription("Excel con los datos del contrato del cliente seleccionado")
                         ->setKeywords("reporte cliente contrato")
                         ->setCategory("Reporte excel");

    $tituloReporte = "Datos del cliente";
    $titulosColumnas = array('COLABORADOR','TELEFONO COLABORADOR','COMERCIAL','NOMBRE','APELLIDOS','DNI','CODIGO POSTAL','DIRECCION','FECHA NACIMIENTO','PROVINCIA','POBLACION','TELEFONO CONTACTO','EMAIL','TIPO CONTRATO','TELEFONO FIJO','OPERADOR ACTUAL','OFERTA','LINEA 1 NUMERO','LINEA 2 NUMERO','LINEA 3 NUMERO','LINEA 4 NUMERO','LINEA 5 NUMERO');

    // Se agregan los titulos del reporte
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                ->setCellValue('A1',$tituloReporte)
                ->setCellValue('A3',  $titulosColumnas[0])
                ->setCellValue('B3',  $titulosColumnas[1])
                ->setCellValue('C3',  $titulosColumnas[2])
                ->setCellValue('D3',  $titulosColumnas[3])
                ->setCellValue('E3',  $titulosColumnas[4])
                ->setCellValue('F3',  $titulosColumnas[5])
                ->setCellValue('G3',  $titulosColumnas[6])
                ->setCellValue('H3',  $titulosColumnas[7])
                ->setCellValue('I3',  $titulosColumnas[8])
                ->setCellValue('J3',  $titulosColumnas[9])
                ->setCellValue('K3',  $titulosColumnas[10])
                ->setCellValue('L3',  $titulosColumnas[11])
                ->setCellValue('M3',  $titulosColumnas[12])
                ->setCellValue('N3',  $titulosColumnas[13])
                ->setCellValue('O3',  $titulosColumnas[14])
                ->setCellValue('P3',  $titulosColumnas[15])
                ->setCellValue('Q3',  $titulosColumnas[16])
                ->setCellValue('R3',  $titulosColumnas[17])
                ->setCellValue('S3',  $titulosColumnas[18])
                ->setCellValue('T3',  $titulosColumnas[19])
                ->setCellValue('U3',  $titulosColumnas[20])
                ->setCellValue('V3',  $titulosColumnas[21]);

    //Se agregan los datos de los alumnos
    $i = 4;
    while ($fila = $misContratos->fetch_array()) {

        $nombre = $fila['nombre'].'_'.$fila['apellidos'];

        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                ->setCellValue('A'.$i,  $fila['colaborador'])
                ->setCellValue('B'.$i,  $fila['telefonoColaborador'])
                ->setCellValue('C'.$i,  $fila['comercial'])
                ->setCellValue('D'.$i,  $fila['nombre'])
                ->setCellValue('E'.$i,  $fila['apellidos'])
                ->setCellValue('F'.$i,  $fila['dni'])
                ->setCellValue('G'.$i,  $fila['cp'])
                ->setCellValue('H'.$i,  $fila['direccion'])
                ->setCellValue('I'.$i,  $fila['fechaNacimiento'])
                ->setCellValue('J'.$i,  $fila['provincia'])
                ->setCellValue('K'.$i,  $fila['poblacion'])
                ->setCellValue('L'.$i,  $fila['telefonoContacto'])
                ->setCellValue('M'.$i,  $fila['email'])
                ->setCellValue('N'.$i,  $fila['tipoContrato'])
                ->setCellValue('O'.$i,  $fila['telefonoFijo'])
                ->setCellValue('P'.$i,  $fila['operadorActual'])
                ->setCellValue('Q'.$i,  $fila['oferta'])
                ->setCellValue('R'.$i,  $fila['linea1numero'])
                ->setCellValue('S'.$i,  $fila['linea2numero'])
                ->setCellValue('T'.$i,  $fila['linea3numero'])
                ->setCellValue('U'.$i,  $fila['linea4numero'])
                ->setCellValue('V'.$i,  $fila['linea5numero']);
            $i++;
    }
    // Se asigna el nombre a la hoja
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Datos Cliente');

    // Se activa la hoja para que sea la que se muestre cuando el archivo se abre
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    // Inmovilizar paneles 
    //$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->freezePane('A4');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->freezePaneByColumnAndRow(0,83);

    // Se manda el archivo al navegador web, con el nombre que se indica (Excel2007)
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="excel.xlsx"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
    exit;
}else{
    print_r('No hay resultados para mostrar');
}
```

La conexion lo hace correctamente, los if de las consultas entra correctamente pero al ejecutarlo llena la pantalla de unos simbolos raros y no descarga el documento

Answer (score 1):

Supongo que los caracteres raros a los que te refieres son los acentos y ñ

estos se solucionan aplicando utf8_encode()

ejemplo

```
  ->setCellValue('A1', utf8_encode($tituloReporte))
```

si no funciona, es por la codificacion en que tienes la base de datos.

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que no está leyendo la línea:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="excel.xlsx"');
```

Creo que si en lugar de poner:

```
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Pones por ejemplo:

```
$objWriter->save('mifichero.xlsx');
```

Te lo va a guardar bien en tu servidor, y si lo abres, verás que se lee con *Excel* sin problemas. Eso quiere decir que no te está leyendo esa línea *header*.

Para que te lo lea debes de tener en cuenta esto: antes que un *header* no puede haber ninguna salida (*echo, print, HTML, ...*) Sino, no te lo leerá bien.

A parte si metes algún fichero *include* o *require*, este debe ser PHP puro, nada de HTML.

Y creo que debería de empezar por `<?php`, pero no terminarlo como de costumbre con `?>`, dejarlo sin esa terminación.